# Maven build : grouping jar files during war build

Tags: java, maven, ant, build

My current webapp contains currently more than 100 java libs which are proprietary.

```
webapp
|_WEB-INF
   |_lib
      |_ com.company.lib1.jar
      |_ com.company.lib2.jar
```

I want to regroup them in a single jar file when I build my webapp with maven, and I want to handle that during the webapp build (not building this beside or something else).

```
webapp
|_WEB-INF
   |_lib
      |_ com.company.all_libs.jar
```

I tried to run a maven ant task to regroup the libs, I got my single jar containing everything but I still have the rest of my libs in my WEB-INF/lib folder.

```
webapp
|_WEB-INF
   |_lib
      |_ com.company.lib1.jar
      |_ com.company.lib2.jar
      |_ com.company.all_libs.jar
```

Snippet of my pom with the ant part :

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>create-full-jar</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>run</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <target>
            <jar destfile="target/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/com.company.all_libs.jar">
              <zipgroupfileset dir="target/webapp/WEB-INF/lib" includes="*.jar" />
            </jar>
          </target>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

I looked at the maven war plugin but I did not manage to find a suitable solution.

Comment: I'd suggest you make a sub-project that, using the [assembly plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) or possibly the [shade plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) (try assembly first; shade is much more powerful but more difficult to use), copies all the dependency jars into one mega-jar, and then your war can depend on that.

Comment: Why do you want to go thru this pain? The War file contain all the jars in a "lib" sub directory? From experience it's also a good idea not to repackage 3rd party software. Think 3 years into the future when you're trying to figure out what the jar is and where it came from. Changing the jar means you can't use sha checksums to search for matches in 3rd party repos like Maven Central

Comment: Finally i don't repackage 3rd party libs
The problem we encounter is the amount of opened files on our production servers. We have commons propietary library that are still not in tomcat shared/lib folder, so I want to repackage them all into one single jar to go from 130 files open per webapp to one file. This times our 10 webapps currently running, it makes a great reduction of opened files number.

The answer from @dcsohl is the one we will use, regrouping all our libraries into one company.bundle project, and using a dependency on only him.

Thanks for your answers by the way :)